# Determine if two MethodInfo instances represent the same (non-virtual) method through inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, reflection, methodinfo

First I give a simple example where I know the answer. Consider:

```
class Animal
{
  public virtual void M() { Console.WriteLine("a"); }
}
class Giraffe : Animal
{
  public override void M() { Console.WriteLine("g"); }
}
```

and then somewhere the code:

```
  var am = typeof(Animal).GetMethod("M");
  var gm = typeof(Giraffe).GetMethod("M");
  Console.WriteLine(am == gm);  // False
  Console.WriteLine(am == gm.GetBaseDefinition());  // True
```

We see that `am` and `gm` are not considered equal, which is entirely fair (the latter is an override of the former). However, with the last line we can determine that these two methods are related; one is a "base method" of the other.

(You can even check for reference equality, `(object)am == (object)gm.GetBaseDefinition()`, and you still get True.)

And now for the situation I have a question for. Consider instead:

```
class Plant
{
  public void N() /* non-virtual */ { }
}
class Tree : Plant
{
}
```

with:

```
  var pn = typeof(Plant).GetMethod("N");
  var tn = typeof(Tree).GetMethod("N");
  Console.WriteLine(pn == tn);  // False
  // How can I determine that 'pn' and 'tn' are in a sense the same method?
```

In this case `pn` and `tn` are still considered different (and their `ReflectedType` differ).

How can I test whether they are in fact (through inheritance) the same method?

Is there any built-in method in the framework? If I will have to work out this by hand, what is the strategy? Must I check that both have same `DeclaringType`, have identical lists of (types of) paramaters, and have the same number of type parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `DeclaringType` property:

```
am.DeclaringType.Dump(); // Animal
gm.DeclaringType.Dump(); // Giraffe

pn.DeclaringType.Dump(); // Plant
tn.DeclaringType.Dump(); // Plant
```

Or you can use `MethodHandle`:

```
(am.MethodHandle == gm.MethodHandle).Dump(); // False

(pn.MethodHandle == tn.MethodHandle).Dump(); // True
```

Though I'm not sure if this is entirely reliable.

If you only care about whether the method is actually overriden in a given type, you can also use the `BindingFlags`:

```
var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;

typeof(Plant).GetMethod("N", flags).Dump(); // N
typeof(Tree).GetMethod("N", flags).Dump(); // null
```

Comment: Will `DeclaringType` be the same for two different classes with the same name declared in separate namespaces? If yes, you might think one class is a base class of the other, when in reality the base class has the same name and is located somewhere else.

Comment: @Kapol `DeclaringType` is not a `string`, it's a `Type` - it's not compared by name, but by type ID.

Comment: @Kapol In fact, relying on names is a bad idea for more reasons than just this - for example, in CLI it's perfectly valid to override a method with a method that has a different name. C# only uses this for explicit interface implementations IIRC, but other languages on the CLI might use for other cases as well (and it's entirely free in IL, of course).

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

Comment: I knew about `DeclaringType` already (mentioned in last part of the question). But `MethodHandle` seems to solve the problem. Will mark this answer as accepted.